# CakePHP 3 One core, multiple apps

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I trying to setup CakePHP 3 with several apps sharing the same CakePHP core. What I'm trying to achieve is having a file structure where 'src' is 'app1', another src-ish folder is 'app2' etc at the same level in the file structure, sharing Core.

The apps are about publications (with different layouts): a verification toolkit, an analysis toolkit, a search gui, an admin-page and a tool for classification. At login, the user is redirected to different controllers depending on username. The apps share dependencies, and the username/organisation etc is stored in session-variables available across the apps.

The solution I've come up with so far is naming the files App1TestController, App2TestController etc.

Anyone knows how to set this up?

Comment: What you are doing is deprecated. With composer it is even bad to share the same dependencies per app. Why are you doing it? It cannot be webspace, as this is quite cheap. I think you are creating problems where there are none. I am pretty sure you have bigger fish to fry.

Comment: I clarified my post somewhat. They are not totally separated as they would share the same start page, session-variables etc. Yeah, it's not about web-space, but to have a better file structure.

Comment: Develop the shared code as plugins that can be shared across multiple apps.

Comment: Shared code as plugins seems like a complicated solution to this quite simple problem..?

Comment: If the apps are _that_ closely linked that they even share the same session, then you could simply develop them as plugins, and make them inherit the shared code from the main app, or even from other plugins. And no, I don't think that plugins are complicated at all. You most probably won't get any better answers here unless you share some more info about what these apps are, what they do, and why exactly they need to be tied together like that.

Comment: Ok, I've edited OP with some more information about the apps. They don't absolutely need to be tied together like that, but that's what I would like.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 3 comes with namespaces, so it is possible to have multiple apps and reuse the vendor directory as an engine.

To load multiple apps, you need to configure your config/bootstap.php, config/paths.php and config/app.php what is the namespace and directory of your app.

I have done this on https://github.com/vttn/app